# Python pandas dataframe regex to extract substring from object

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I created a dataframe in python using pandas module from a csv file. Pandas by default converted string into object type. Now from that string, I wanted to create another column which I am trying to create using regex. However, because the column is object I am getting error

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop\train.csv')
desig = re.search(r'(\w+), (\w+). (\w+)',data['Name']).group(1)
```

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

How can I extract the portion from the object?

Thanks.

Comment: You should also show us a few lines from the CSV file so that we may ascertain what you are trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the vectorised operations contained in the `str` methods of the dataframe:

```
data['desig'] = data['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w+), (\w+). (\w+)')
```

This will actually return a dataframe with three columns corresponding to the three groups.